# Issue with Avatax on UAT environment

Tags: java

I am having sandbox account of Avalara(Avatax) and that is working fine on my local system and also on the staging environment. But the same sandbox credentials are not working on the UAT instance.

Error logged: `avaTaxConnection java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

This is the code snippet I used :

```
try {

      client = new AvaTaxClient("PriceBook", "1.0", "https://sandbox- 
              rest.avatax.com/api/v2/utilities/ping",            AvaTaxEnvironment.Sandbox).withSecurity(PropertiesFileConfiguration.Avatax_AccountID,
              PropertiesFileConfiguration.Avatax_LicenseKey);
      PingResultModel ping = client.ping();

      if (ping.getAuthenticated()) {
        return client;
      }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("ERROR in avaTaxConnection " + e);
}
```

When I am trying to get `PingResultModel` ping on the basis of the client object getting the exception: `avaTaxConnection java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`.

I have also checked whether the connection is created or not, but the connection is created successfully. I printed the connection object in logs.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for that `SocketException`?

Comment: No, I have not printed the stack trace will print that and update it here.

Comment: @Abra in stack trace I am getting only the above error nothing else.